# Find file names based on the timestamp name of the file,

Tags: php, linux, bash

I have a directory where logs files are continuously being pushed by a remote ftp. An example of the file name is '20140222_Activity' which is YYYY-MM-DD_Activity. I already finished writing a php app that can remotely execute commands on the linux machine and retrieve output.

I want to integrate a feature that would do the following. User is promoted to write the starting time stamp for example 20140222 , and the ending time stamp 20140227 on the php app. The data is relayed to a bash command that is executed on the linux machine and data is relayed back to php app. The problem I am having is the following:

```
find /opt/p_logs/vlogs/300/[$Start_time-$End_time]_Activity.log | xargs head -n 2
```

where `$Start_time` and `$End_time` is the `$_POST` data from the php form.

I can retrieve data if the `$Start_time` and `$End_time` stamp is 0-9 but here it is 8 digits long(20140222) , seems to me that regex is the problem here, So if I have like 4 files in the directory which are 20140222_Activity ... 20140226_Activty.

How can I make the above command return the the files with respect to the timetsamp provided?. like if the start stamp is 20140223 and ending is 20140225 only return the file of names between this range, sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `seq` to create the sequence of numbers between the start and end dates, then loop over that sequence to run your command:

```bash
for f in $(seq -f "%.0f" $start_time $end_time); do 
    # do whatever you want to the file here
    head -2 "/opt/p_logs/vlogs/300/${f}_Activity"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with a single `find` command, as find does not provide for this type of filename comparison.

But instead of searching for matching filenames, you could just generate the names and open the files explicitly:

```
for name in $( seq -f "/opt/p_logs/vlogs/300/%.0f_Activity" $Start_time $End_time); do
    [[ -f $name ]] && head -n 2 $name
done
```

A list of paths to files with continous numbers between `$Start_time` and `$End_time` is generated by `seq` and used in the loop. `head` is called if the file exists and is a regular file.